# can't initialize IWICImagingFactory in a direct2d project

Tags: c++, direct2d

i'm creating a direct2d project and i can't load a bitmap picture because the object of the class IWICImagingFactory is null. i don't know if i am calling correctly the function CoCreateInstance.

this is the code i am using for initialize everything:

```
// ... d2dFactory ... and others objects
IWICImagingFactory* pIWICFactory = 0;

HRESULT TDE_Device::Initialize(HWND hwnd)
{
    HRESULT hr = D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, &d2dFactory);
    //
    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
    //
    D2D1_SIZE_U size = D2D1::SizeU(rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top);
    d2dFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(),     D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(hwnd, size), &MainD2DCore.d2dRenderTarg);
    wndHandle = hwnd;
    //
    // ----------  HERE IS THE CoCreateInstance ------------------------
    CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICImagingFactory, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IWICImagingFactory, reinterpret_cast<void **>(&pIWICFactory));
    if (pIWICFactory == 0)
    {
        // I GET THIS MESSAGE
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Error creating the Image Factory", L"ERROR", MB_OK);
        return E_FAIL;
    }
    //
    return hr;
}
```

when i try to use this IWICImagingFactory for load a picture from file, i get the Access violation exception because is reading the address 0x0.

what the correct way to call the function CoCreateInstance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is the correct way of creating an ImagingFactory but
did you call CoInitializeEx( NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED); befor calling CoCreateInstance?

Comment: no, I didn't know it was necessary, but now it works! thanks a lot!

Comment: FYI: I wouldn't keep IWICImagingFactory* pIWICFactory around as global - it has caused random crashes in my application. Recreate the factory every time you need it and release it after you are done. In short make it a short lived object.